# Docker for Windows (Linux Containers) Cannot Mount Windows network Drive

Tags: docker

In the latest update to Docker (v2.2.1.0), I am not able to mount a network share into a container. For example, say I have a windows share drive "S" on the host, then the following command returns nothing because (I think) the "S" drive is not recognized.

```sh
docker run --rm -it -v "S:/:/mounted" bash ls /mounted
```

In the past, (I believe) I at least saw that network drives were available to be checked in the docker settings, however now I only see "C", and not "S".

Also in the past, when I ran the above code, I would be prompted to accept that I am trying to connect to a network share.

Has anyone been able to perform the volume mounting that I am trying to achieve?

Comment: did you solve this? currently experiencing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

In the settings dialog, click on Shared Drives. This should be able to list down the drives that you have avaible on your windows machine.In my case, I have C drive and i have chosen to share since i want to expose the folder to my containers